# Qt - splitting a QString by several types of whitespaces without RegExp

Tags: c++, qt, split, whitespace, qstring

everyone. I need to split a QString by any type of whitespaces as fast as possible. Now I am using QRegExp, but this method takes a lot of time. Is there a faster option to do that?

```
QString l = "one two  three   four    five"; 
lst = l.split(QRegExp("\\s+"), QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c)

Comment: @zett42 He's using Qt, not generic C++ methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only other way I could know is by using the [simplified()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#simplified) method:

```
QString l = "one two  three   four    five";
QStringList lst = l.simplified().split(" ");
```

I have no idea how it compares in performance against regexp though.